# How do I create a web link inside a javascript function and pass cell value as a parameter to servlet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am creating a table dynamically with JavaScript as you can see below. I want users to be able to click on the first column value and pass the value of the cell as a parameter to a J@EE servlet. Can you help me? Basically the first column should be links to a new page with a country details. How can I do that? Thank you.

Where do I put the link code?

```
function oneSecondFunction() {
$.get('DisplayCountries', function(responseJson) {
    if (responseJson != null) {
        $("#countrytable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var table1 = $("#countrytable");
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
            var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>" +
                    "<td></td><td></td></tr>");
            rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['id']);
            rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['country1']);
            rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['country2']);
            rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['country3']);
            rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['country4']);
            rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['country5']);
            rowNew.children().eq(6).text(value['country6']);
            rowNew.children().eq(7).text(value['country7']);
            rowNew.children().eq(8).text(value['country8']);

            rowNew.appendTo(table1);
        });
    }
});
```

and here is the link code. I have tried several options and it doesn't work.

```
<a href="DisplayDetails ? & param=<%=id%>">id</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, assign a `class` to the first `<td>` something like `<td class="linkHolder">`.

Then, write a click handler to send ajax request to servlet:

```
$('#countrytable').on('click', '.linkHolder', function() {
       var link = $(this).html();
       $.post('/myservlet', {url: link}, function(response) {
          //handle response here
       });
      return false;
});
```

You can access the link on the servlet side with the request parameter `url`

Comment: I am sorry I am new to ajax. can you provide a complete code? Thank you.

Comment: I have already given you the code. Try and play around with that. Up-vote/accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: I cannot figure it out? Sorry.

Comment: Do I have to create linkHolder class in CSS?

Comment: I have added class to td but it doesn't make it a link.

Comment: Ok I have finally made it work. I can pass url parameter to the servlet. But servlet supposed to forward user to another jsp page but it doesn't happen. I can see on the console that servlet receives the paramater and processes it. But it doesn't forward to another jsp page. How can I fix that? Thanks.